# Can I display a list of the tabs in a side-pane?

Tags: tabbed-user-interface

can I display a list of the tabs in a side pane, so you can switch by selecting from it? Something similar to NERDTree's pane.

I want to be able to toggle it into view, select the tab I want in switch to it.

If it can expand show a list of windows in that pane that you can switch to directly, that will even be better.

Comment: Also posted here: https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/67c8f4/is_there_a_plugin_that_displays_the_list_of_tabs/

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not. There are however a number of plugins to handle tabs and buffers.

Given that you want to see tabs per window, my recommendation would be to have a look at [vim-wintabs](https://github.com/zefei/vim-wintabs).

[image]

It will also show buffers per window in a line.

On a more general note, I would recommend reading [this stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26708822/why-do-vim-experts-prefer-buffers-over-tabs) for an excellent explanation of windows, tabs and buffers and their use in vim.